# Processing JSON response in an ASP.NET webform

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

I'm sending an HTTPWebRequest to a service and they are returning a userid in JSON.

They are returning:

```
{"id: 123456"}
```

How do I process this?  Should I just do a split on the `:` and take the second element or is there a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do that or use a json serializer to deserialize it

if you are using .net 3.5 have a look at [system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You could do that, of course, but for anything more complex than that, I would strongly suggest you look at something like [Json.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json) to handle the deserialization for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of the object and you are using .net 3.5 you could add a Reference to `System.ServiceModel.Web` and serialize the object doing this:

```
var o = new DataContractJsonSerializer(
            typeof(YourClassHere)).ReadObject(Page.Request.InputStream);
```